# INSERT IGNORE/UPDATE IGNORE equivalency in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've got the following table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.UserOrgUnits
(
    UserOrgUnitId int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    UserId int NOT NULL,
    OrgUnitId int NOT NULL,
    DateUpdated int NOT NULL,
    UpdatedByUserId int NOT NULL,
    IsActive int NOT NULL,
    VersionNumber int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserOrgUnits_Users FOREIGN KEY (UserId)
       REFERENCES Users (UserId) 
               ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserOrgUnits_OrgUnits FOREIGN KEY (OrgUnitId) 
       REFERENCES OrgUnits (OrgUnitId)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_UserOrgUnitsCreated 
                 ON dbo.UserOrgUnits (UserId, OrgUnitId, DateUpdated);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_UserOrgUnits 
                 ON dbo.UserOrgUnits (UserId, OrgUnitId);
```

And below is an example of the rows in the db.

```
INSERT INTO UserOrgUnits (UserId, OrgUnitId, DateUpdated, UpdatedByUserId, IsActive, 
                          VersionNumber) 
                  VALUES (1, 2, 1523639062, 6, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO UserOrgUnits (UserId, OrgUnitId, DateUpdated, UpdatedByUserId, IsActive, 
                          VersionNumber) 
                  VALUES (2, 2, 1523639062, 6, 1, 1);
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that I have a number of tables similar to the one above that need to be updated, specifically, I'm trying to update the OrgUnits from one to another. (A move from OrgUnit A->OrgUnit B) so I'm using a stored procedure and creating a transaction. At the beginning of the stored procedure I get the values of the OrgUnitId I need to move as values `@from`, `@to`.

But if I try to simply perform an

```
UPDATE UserOrgUnits SET OrgUnitId = @to, 
                        DateUpdated = 1523639511, 
                        UpdatedByUserId = 6
                  WHERE OrgUnitId = @from;
```

I obviously get the following error

`Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.UserOrgUnits' with unique index 'UQ_UserOrgUnits'. The duplicate key value is (1, 2).`

In MySQL or Maria I would simply fire an UPDATE IGNORE but in SQL Server 08 I know that's not possible so in such a situation I thought it would be best to simply to merge the two rows.

i.e.

```
DECLARE @from INT;
DECLARE @to INT;
DECLARE @now INT = (SELECT dbo.UNIX_TIMESTAMP(GETDATE()));
DECLARE @Updater INT = (SELECT  UserId FROM Users WHERE Username = 'root');
DECLARE @OrigOrgUnit NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT TOP 1 @from = OrgUnitId FROM OrgUnits 
                                        WHERE OrgUnitKey = ' + <incoming orig key>;
DECLARE @NewOrgUnit NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT TOP 1 @to = OrgUnitId FROM OrgUnits 
                                        WHERE OrgUnitKey = ' + <incoming new key>;
EXEC sp_executesql @OrigOrgUnit, N'@from INT OUT', @from OUT;
EXEC sp_executesql @NewOrgUnit, N'@to INT OUT', @to OUT;

MERGE UserOrgUnits AS t
USING (VALUES (@from, @to, @now, @Updater)) AS s([from], [to], [now], [updater])
ON t.OrgUnitId = s.[to] AND t.UserId = s.UserId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET OrgUnitId = s.[to], Updater = s.[updater], DateUpdated = s.[now];
```

But now I'm getting an error stating `An action of type 'UPDATE' is not allowed in the 'WHEN NOT MATCHED' clause of a MERGE statement.`

Clearly I'm not using the MERGE statement properly. I was wondering if there was another statement(s) something that would be more appropriate to use? If so what would be the best way to go about doing so?

Comment: MERGE essentially uses a join between the target and the source in order to determine which rows to insert, update, and delete. How can it perform an update if there is no match? I tend to recommend against using MERGE, especially when your actual intended actions are easier to describe using traditional insert / update / delete queries. There are common misconceptions about MERGE that make it seem like a better choice, [**but in most cases it's not**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).